# Using REST Assured, how can I check if a field is present or not in an array of json objects type of response?

Tags: json, rest-assured, jsonpath, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to validate that a response like the one below contains some fields. I am not interested in the fields value - just that the keys exist.
For example I want to check that the key "id" is present in this type of response. How would I accomplish that?

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "title":"Title",
      "details":"details",
      "benefit":"Welcome",
      "expirationTimestamp":1549995900,
      "notice":"some text",     
   }
]
```

If I do

```
given()
  .spec(reqSpec).
when()
  .get().
then()
  .body("$", hasKey("id"));
```

I get an error like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path $ doesn't match.
Expected: map containing ["id"->ANYTHING]
  Actual: [{blabla=something, id=1, details=details, etc=etc}]
```

Please, can someone explain to me how this should work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
given()
  .spec(reqSpec).
when()
  .get().
then()
  .body("[0]", hasKey("id"));
```

Groovy GPath is used in Rest Assured. You can take a look at their guide [here](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath)

Also there's a good tutorial [here](https://james-willett.com/2017/05/rest-assured-gpath-json/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! Do you by any chance also know how I can check if the response has returned only one json object in the array and not 2 or more?

Comment: @JustNatural Try this one _.body("$", hasSize(1))_

Comment: Is there any we can check multiple fields. What if we have 50 fields and want to check.